# How do I move the methods to another class and call it?

Tags: c#

I'm making a game called "Lingo" for my programming class. I have gotten most of it to work. But we are supposed to have as little code in the form class as possible. So I have to move most of it to another class. Any ideas on how I should do it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace Lingo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        AboutBox1 about = new AboutBox1();
        int gissningar, x, score, highcsore;
        Label[] labels = new Label[25];
        string ord;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            gissningar = 0;
            x = 0;
            score = 1000;
            highcsore = 0;
            labels[0] = label1;
            labels[1] = label2;
            labels[2] = label3;
            labels[3] = label4;
            labels[4] = label5;
            labels[5] = label6;
            labels[6] = label7;
            labels[7] = label8;
            labels[8] = label9;
            labels[9] = label10;
            labels[10] = label11;
            labels[11] = label12;
            labels[12] = label13;
            labels[13] = label14;
            labels[14] = label15;
            labels[15] = label16;
            labels[16] = label17;
            labels[17] = label18;
            labels[18] = label19;
            labels[19] = label20;
            labels[20] = label21;
            labels[21] = label22;
            labels[22] = label23;
            labels[23] = label24;
            labels[24] = label25;
            String[] ordLista = File.ReadAllLines(("words.txt").ToString());
            ord = ordLista[r.Next(r.Next(ordLista.Length))];
            ord = ord.ToUpper();
            labels[0].Text = Convert.ToString(ord[0]);
        }

        private void quitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            about.Show();
        }

        private void addWordsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new Form2().Show();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ordet = ord;
            string svar = textBox1.Text.ToUpper();
            if (Regex.IsMatch(svar, "^[a-zA-Z]{5}$"))
            {
                if (x <= 20)
                {

                    if (svar == ord)
                        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
                        {

                            labels[i + x].Text = Convert.ToString(svar[i]);
                            labels[i + x].BackColor = Color.Green;
                            highcsore = score;
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        gissningar++;
                        score = score / gissningar;
                        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
                        {
                            labels[i + x].BackColor = Color.Red;
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
                        {
                            labels[i + x].Text = Convert.ToString(svar[i]);
                            if (svar[i] == ord[i])
                            {

                                labels[i + x].BackColor = Color.Green;
                                ordet = ordet.Insert(i, "?");
                                ordet = ordet.Remove(i + 1, 1);
                                if (x < 20)
                                {
                                    labels[x + 5].Text = Convert.ToString(ord[0]);
                                    labels[i + x + 5].Text = Convert.ToString(svar[i]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
                        {
                            for (int k = 0; k <= 4; k++)
                            {
                                if (svar[i] == ordet[k])
                                {

                                    labels[i + x].BackColor = Color.Orange;
                                    svar = svar.Insert(i, "#");
                                    svar = svar.Remove(i + 1, 1);
                                }



                            }
                        }

                    }
                    //kod för att jämföra chars


                    x = x + 5;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Du förlorade! \r\n Ordet var: " + ord);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ordet måste ha 5 bokstäver");
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You'll be doing yourself a giant favor if you go to your teacher and explain that you don't know how to create classes and methods in C#.  You'll learn a lot more than you would from copying and pasting code from a forum.

Comment: Classes are supposed to have a single responsibility, which then results in a single class having as little code as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure copying/pasting everything in another class/method is the answer.

You'd better refactoring your code in "layers" : game logic, render/graphic logic, action with the user...

Answer (score 0):

Select the chunk of code you want to move to class and Right Click -> Refactor -> Generate Method..

This will generate a method with all dependants as Input, and then you can move the functions to another class or class library!

**UPDATE:**
Before you refactor, separate your logic code from controls as Daniel said in the comment.. This will help you keep your logic in a class file and controls on form class! You can send inputs from your controls to class functions/methods as parameters!

Comment: Thanks I will certainly try that :)

Comment: This doesn't really help as his code directly works on the UI controls. He first would need to seperate it from those controls to be able to make useful refactorings.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making a "Game" class. This class would hold all of the game initialization and setup logic. So in it you'd probably have a `init()` that performs most of what you have in your constructor. Most of those properties you have at the beginning of the class should also be moved into this new class.

I'm not sure what the code in `button1_Click` does, but there would also be a `doGameLogic` method. This class here should create a new instance of your game and access game specific members and logic via the game class. Your form class should work with the controls you need for your game.